# How to create column with sub colum (under) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long data sheet with many questions. There are many questions with two or more answers, like below:

```
Q:1 is there electricity in your home    Q:2 What are the electric appliances in your home
    yes                                         tv
    yes                                         fridge
    no                                          laptop
    no                                          computer
    yes                                          tv
    yes                                          laptop
```

I want the output result as below:

```
Q:1 is there electricity in your home    Q:2 What are the electric appliances in your home
total    yes    no                        total    tv    fridge    laptop    computer
6        4       2                        6         2       1        2        1
```

I want an additional column of "total" and a "total of Yes or No or TV" in other columns as well, as shown in the photo above.
Thank you all for your help.

Edit: The first column is a question (Q1 & Q2). The below rows are the answers from different people in the survey. It is a sample for your understanding.

Comment: Will you please provide your dataframes as text?

Comment: It's a survey questionnaire form with more than 60 questions in columns. the survey was done through Kobocollecttool and I have the output sheet. In the form there was a question like above (with select-one option, yes or no). In other questions the answer were select-many format. I am doing the analysis.

Comment: Can you just copy the text you screenshotted and paste it into the post? It doesn't need to look good :)

Comment: please check the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible approach. You can iterate each column, calculate the frequency of each value in this column, and create a new multi-index dataframe:

```
new_df = list()
for column in df:
    column_count = df[column].value_counts().to_frame().stack()
    column_count.loc[("total", column)] = column_count.sum()
    new_df.append(column_count)
```

Now, let's create a single dataframe with all those counts (one per column) and pivot the table to format the output:

```
new_df = pd.concat(new_df).reset_index()
new_df = new_df.pivot_table(index=["level_1", "level_0"], values=0).T
```

This is the output of the code with the sample input:

```
# Sample input
    Q1      Q2
0  yes      tv
1  yes  fridge
2   no  laptop
3   no      tv

# Sample output
level_1 Q1               Q2                
level_0 no total yes fridge laptop total tv
0        2     4   2      1      1     4  2
```